# Is there a simple way to infer fields for PostgreSQL upsert?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The way I know to do an upsert in PostgreSQL currently is as such, but with many fields, and with many tables it seems redundant to have to redefine the fields to be updated, when the insert values are already given:

```sql
INSERT INTO a (c1, c2, c3... c21)
VALUES (v1, v2, v3... v21)
ON CONFLICT (c1) 
DO UPDATE SET
    c1=EXCLUDED.c1
    c2=EXCLUDED.c2
    c3=EXCLUDED.c3
    ...
    c21=EXCLUDED.c21
```

Assume the table has 22 columns, c22 being a field that has a default or shouldn't be updated if exists

Is there a way to infer the fields from the insert command like `DO UPDATE SET *=EXCLUDED.*` and update ONLY the columns defined in the insert command without having to explicitly name every field?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `EXCLUDED` values from a `ROW`. Doing so you at least don't need to repeat the `EXLCUDED` multiple times, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,1,1)
ON CONFLICT (c1) DO UPDATE
SET (c1, c2, c3) = ROW(EXCLUDED.*);
```

Demo 1: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9422c916d86100c07646e4d9eb591b02)

In case not all columns are being used in the `INSERT`, you need to tell which columns are supposed to be inserted and you need to set **all columns** in the `SET` list. There is a caveat though: columns declared with a `DEFAULT` value will be overwritten with the default value and the others will be set to `NULL`, which is a pretty much useless feature in most use cases, but for the sake of completion I will add another demo:

```
INSERT INTO a (c1,c2) VALUES (1,3) 
ON CONFLICT (c1) DO UPDATE
SET (c1,c2,c3) = ROW(EXCLUDED.*); -- c3 will become either NULL or DEFAULT
```

Demo 2: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae6393a56ad4c593355782d7b2e0cd67)

Comment: This does not work if INSERT INTO doesn't use every field for example, omitting a default field. it will error with "number of columns does not match number of values"

Comment: @IsaacN this wasn't clear in your question. I'm afraid there is no way to get just a subset of `EXCLUDED` without accessing the columns one by one.

Comment: @IsaacN I just updated my answer with a few more info.

Comment: My bad, I didn't think it would matter as I did mention to infer from the INSERT columns rather than replace all columns. I also forgot to include the fact that any columns not included should not be replaced with NULL/DEFAULT in an UPDATE as well. Judging by your answer it would seem that this behavior is not possible without explicit column naming

Comment: @IsaacN if you want to replace the not used columns with default or null values, wouldn't the second query be what you want?

Comment: should **NOT** be replaced with NULL/DEFAULT in an UPDATE as well

Comment: @IsaacN you mean **NOT NULL**? If so, it will also raise an exception, as NOT NULL is also a constraint ;)

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be a chain of misunderstandings here let me rephrase the behavior I am trying to achieve in a simpler example:
Table has 3 columns, `a, b, c` assume no defaults or anything, insert would leave `c` null
`INSERT INTO (a, b) VALUES (a, b) + UPSERT stuff here` should only update `a` and `b` if there is a conflict. `c` should retain its value from before the UPSERT (your answer would set it to NULL or DEFAULT. I want to avoid that hence my phrasing that it should **NOT** be replaced)

Comment: @IsaacN I see, in this case I don't think there is a way to do that without writing the columns + excluded one by one. I will leave the answer here for future reference :) good luck and don't forget to report if you find a better solution. cheers